# Android Studio showing error like "Expected a name but was STRING at line 1 column 99 path $[0].apkInfo.versionName" while generating signed apk

Tags: android, signed-apk

I am trying to generate signed apk of my application but this is showing error

> Expected a name but was STRING at line 1 column 99 path $[0].apkInfo.versionName

Project Level gradle is:

```
buildscript {
repositories {

    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.roosterlogic.smartpaani.smartpaanimaintenance"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 5
    versionName "2.3"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'

implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
}
```

Android Studio 3.1
While upgrading I have shifted to gradle 3.1.1 but now I step down at 3.0.1.

What is problem behind this help.

Comment: How's your ProDuard file? Were you able to build signed APKs prior to the update?

Comment: In  proguard-rules.pro   file everything is commented. I diidn't change this file.

Answer (score 2):

recheck the target folder you are going to make your apk. If there is existing apk or json files remove them and try again...

Comment: This totally worked for me today. I was baffled and the problem was abundantly unclear from the error message so thanks a lot for posting this here!

Answer (score 0):

With Gradle 3.1.x you have to set target SDK to 27.
So make changes accordingly to build apk with new gradle.

As per [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#3-1-0)

> 3.1.0 (March 2018)
>
> This version of the Android plugin requires the following:
>
> Gradle 4.4 or higher.
>
> Build Tools 27.0.3 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Only this worked for me. Adding to my app/build.gradle:

```
android {
...


    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
...
}
```